# Redirecting https exception

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm currently using .htaccess to force https on all pages of my website and it works as it should. However, when making an http (not https) curl request in cmd line, I get a 'page has moved' response because of this rewrite rule. I need to let the script respond with something like this: `"error": { "message" : "This API is only accessible over HTTPS ...` which means that the plain http request needs to hit the script. How can I modify this .htaccess file to allow plain http access to `http://examplesite.com/api/index`?

```
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these 2 rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule     !^api/index https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule     ^api/index http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```